# Adding to Prototype.js Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I have a website that has lots of prototype.js ajax calls and now we need a function called before each of them.  Is there a way to add to the function without actually changing the prototype.js script?  Basically we are looking for a way so we don't have to go and update every call.

For example:

```
OLD:
new Ajax.Request(SOMEURL);

NEW:
somefunction();
new Ajax.Request(SOMEURL);
```

Is there a way to create the same thing as the NEW, but within the Ajax.Request?

Thanks,

Comment: By "not overwriting" do you mean you don't want to edit the source, or do you neither want to patch the function somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah I don't want to edit the source as I don't want to have to always modify every update of prototype.  What I would like is if I could somehow add/extend it in a separate js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype provides [`Ajax.Responders`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Responders/) so you can do this:

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
    onCreate: someFunction
});
```